# Primary Key no genera error al reescribir un valor

Tags: python, sqlite3

Necesito que cuando yo digite un valor que ya este dentro de una tabla entonces sqlite lanze un error por ser Primary Key, pero no consigo que lo haga.

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("Test.db")

lector = db.cursor()

try:
    lector.execute('''CREATE TABLE TEST (
    COD VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY)''')
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    pass

a = input("Digita tu nombre: ")

try:

    lector.execute("INSERT INTO TEST (COD) VALUES(?)", (a,))

except:

    print("El valor ya ha sido creado.")

lector.execute("SELECT * FROM TEST")

print(lector.fetchall())

db.close()
```

Comment: Si quieres evitarte complicaciones lee sobre el ORM http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/ entre otras cosas te obliga a definir bien un modelo de bases de datos para que no tengas estos problemas.

Comment: Puse la parte en donde se ingresa y valida un dato dentro de un while y funciona perfectamente. Hay algo que me esté perdiendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un concepto que es fundamental en Bases de Datos que es el de la `transacción`, básicamente es una o más operaciones de modificación de tablas, es decir `insert/delete/update` (y otras en algunos casos) que se tratan como una operación única, o funciona todo o funciona nada.

En tu caso, el único `INSERT` que estás haciendo es tu única transacción, y aunque no lo veas explícitamente, hay una transacción detrás. Las transacciones, se confirman (`commit`) o se deshacen (`rollback`). La única forma de "confirmar" los cambios en los datos es mediante un `commit`, mientras esto no ocurra, l**os cambios solo son visibles dentro de la transacción** y no son salvados físicamente.

En general, las bases de datos mayores, establecen un `autocommit` por instrucción, y dejan a los desarrolladores, la potestad de construir transacciones con sentencias explicitas `begin transaction/commit transaction/rollback transaction`. En el caso de **Sqlite**, según la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

> The underlying sqlite3 library operates in autocommit mode by default,
> but the Python sqlite3 module by default does not.

Por defecto no se usa el modo autocommit, es decir que es necesario ejecutar un `commit` explícito para salvar los cambios que hiciste.

Cuando haces una sola inserción, lo que ocurre es que la fila no se salva finalmente en la tabla (al no tener un `commit` explícito), por lo que la siguiente ejecución, al no haber filas, no vas a tener errores.

En caso que la inserción la pongas en un ciclo, ahí si falla, por que los cambios, si bien no han sido "commiteados", lo tienes en memoria, en la transacción actual que engloba todos los `insert` que hayas realizado dentro del ciclo.

Finalmente, la solución pasaría por hacer:

```
lector.execute("INSERT INTO TEST (COD) VALUES(?)", (a,))
db.commit()
```